# Fail to plot this implicit function

Tags: plotting, implicit

So I need to plot an implicit function and I used the following but ended up with an empty plot:

```
ContourPlot[
 tanh (1.602*10^-19*y/(4*1.381*10^-23*(24.5 + 273.15))) == 
  tanh (1.602*10^-19*(-15.6*0.001)/(4*1.381*10^-23*(24.5 + 273.15)))*
   exp (0.3288*(0.33 - x)), {x, 0, 10}, {y, -0.02, 0}]
```

When I evaluate at `x=0`, y is calculated as -0.017, so I don't understand why there's not even a point on the plot. Can someone help, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made very simple syntax errors (incorrect `Tanh[]`, `Exp[]`, etc.):

```
ContourPlot[
 Tanh[1.602*10^-19*y/(4*1.381*10^-23*(24.5 + 273.15))] == 
  Tanh[1.602*10^-19*(-15.6*0.001)/(4*1.381*10^-23*(24.5 + 
          273.15))] Exp[0.3288*(0.33 - x)], {x, 0, 10}, {y, -0.02, 0}]
```

Also, it is poor form to include asterisks for multiplication, and to leave multiplicands unevaluated (i.e., using 4*1.381 instead of 5.524) and likewise for addition (24.5+273.15 instead of 297.65).

If you apply `Simplify` to your equation you find:

```
ContourPlot[
 Tanh[9.74323 y] == -0.168121 E^(-0.3288 x),
 {x, 0, 10}, {y, -0.02, 0}]
```

Isn't that simpler?  Don't you think you'll get more help if you do that first?

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! New to mathematica, and it's really cool!

Comment: @Wheeeee "Cool" is an understatement.  *Mathematica* is a revolution.

Comment: Yes! That's much nicer. By the way, do you know how to plot the derivative of y as a function of x?. It's an implicit function, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Probably a bit complex for a beginner, but here:  `Plot[Evaluate[D[(y /. Solve[Tanh[9.7432 y] == -0.1681 E^(-0.3228 x), y][[1]]), x]], {x, 0, 2}] // Quiet`

Comment: Thanks!! Made my day! Mathematica is amazing!

Comment: I don't agree with the second part of your "poor form" sentence. It is quite common in programming to leave expressions with constants as they are instead of compressing them to their final result. You don't gain much in speed if you do the latter but you do lose the mnemonic value. The 24.5+273.15 term, for instance, is clearly a conversion of 24.5 deg C to K and provides better understanding of what's going on there. Of course, defining symbolic constants is even better.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It *is* indeed poor form to post a question that has irrelevant attributes.  Everyone complains about this again and again, as they should.  Question posters should pare down to create the *minimal* example, and the current question would have been much simpler had the poser done so.

Comment: Please don't feel offended as it is not my intention to do so. As posted in your answer it sounded like a general programming advice (which I don't agree with). You did not seem to be aiming at its specific appearance on this forum. Your advice to avoid the asterisk for multiplication is not prompted by the necessity to get a minimal example as the alternative, a space, takes just as much space. It's just a matter of taste.